# Flutter Not Scaling AppBar for Tablet

Tags: flutter, user-interface, scaling, tablet, flutter-appbar

I am designing a Flutter App, and am currently trying to make sure my app works on all screen sizes. When checking my app on an AVD Tablet (Nexus 10) I noticed that widgets like the AppBar and FloatingActionButton don't scale to the screen size, I managed to manually scale the FAB although it seemed weird that it didn't scale automatically. However I have not managed to scale the AppBar to a normal size. Is the app bar meant to be this small on tablets? Is this the standard and it just doesn't look good on an emulator? If not how can this be fixed? I created a test app and the results were the same.

Pic:

[image: Flutter Tablet]

Answer (score 0):

you can try this library ... Responsive Frame Work For Flutter ...
https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework